# SL5 ComponentOne C1FlexGrid dropdowns dynamic filtering

Tags: dynamic, filtering, silverlight-5.0, componentone, c1flexgrid

I am using SL5 based [ComponentOne's](http://www.componentone.com/SuperPages/AboutComponentOne/) [C1FlexGrid](http://www.componentone.com/superproducts/flexgridwinforms/) and binding data to the control at runtime. For two columns, I am populating lookup data as dropdowns in the first and second column of the control. In the first column, I am binding company information and in the second column, I am binding department information by default. There is a 1-N relation between Company and Department entities in my model (that is, for every company, there are N no of departments associated to it).

In edit mode, I want to filter out departments in the second column of the control for the selected company in the first column (that is, when I select "company 1" in the dropdown, I want to bind only those departments associated to company 1 in the second dropdown). Is 
this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by following the suggestion mentioned in the forum post *[Different drop down list/combo box in the same column?](http://our.componentone.com/groups/silverlight/flexgrid-for-silverlight/forum/topic/different-drop-down-listcombo-box-in-the-same-column/)* .